# erasing with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have tons of lines in a file and I wanna know if sed can erase whatever it is after a column

for example , changing this:

`a20 is (on) Jan 15`

for:

`a20 is (on)`

Comment: Do you want to remove all lines after this one? Shorten all lines *with* the text? Or shorten all lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. If you want to remove everything on every line, after a parenthesis, simply use:

```
sed -i 's/).*/)/' file.txt
```

What the above does is "match everything after a parenthesis, and replace the whole match with just a parenthesis".

This being said, the simplest tool is usually the correct one. `cut` provides a very simple way to "cut up" a line into blocks, based on the `delimiter` you pass to it. For example:

```
cut -d" " -f -3 file.txt
```

Now, if your file is a bit different, and the third column doesn't necessarily end with a parenthesis, you can use `awk` instead. Awk provides a lot more control, and is a lot more fine-grained than `cut`.

For example:

```
awk -F' ' '{ print $1, $2, $3 }' file.txt
```

What the above does is separate every line, using the character passed with `-F` as field separator. Then, it prints the three first fields, separating them by the same field separator (`OFS`).

Comment: `print $1, $2, $3` is the same, but more elegant, than `print $1 OFS $2 OFS $3`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks Glenn, I wasn't aware of that. I'll edit my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 3):

You could try cut instead:

```
cut -d " " -f -3 FILENAME
```

Answer (score 1):

**`awk`** is the tool which deal with tabular data very well:

```
$ awk -v n=4 '{for(i=n;i<=NF;i++)$i=""}1' file.txt
```

**`cut`** is yet another tool (sometimes, you need to squeeze white-spaces with `tr` before `cut`):

```
$ cat file.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1-3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "a20 is (on) Jan 15" | sed 's/\(\s*\S*\)\{2\}$//'
a20 is (on)
```

working backwards is sometimes easier, or forwards:

```
echo "a20 is (on) Jan 15" | sed 's/\(\S*\(\s*\S*\)\{2\}\).*/\1/'
a20 is (on)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned the perl way (which as opposed to sed -i, works on platforms that don't use GNU sed): `perl -p -i -e 's/(on).*/(on)/' filename`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use sed:

```
sed 's/^\([^ ][^ ]* [^ ][^ ]* [^ ][^ ]*\).*/\1/' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Add the "-i" switch after sed and (in bash) the file will be edited in-place (i.e. input and output are the same).  Make a backup first while you test this.

Some versions of sed will let you use extended regular expressions which makes the syntax more friendly.  Use the "-r" switch:

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+).*/\1/' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

`[^ ]` means all characters except space.
`[^ ]*` means zero or more of any character except space
`[^ ]+` means one or more of any character except space
`\1` means substitute with first bracketed expression
Of course, you could always use cut instead :-) :

```
cut -f-3 -d" " file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: That has to be the ugliest sed code I have seen so far... o_O

Comment: @Glenn - Good catch.  I've corrected the code.  I wasn't able to test it.  It may be ugly, but it answers the question.  I would almost certainly use cut in my code.